# Why do I get an error: Cannot find module after downloading node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I am having an issue with node.js, I installed Node, Homebrew and Xcode but when I type in the terminal: node index.js I get this error: 
    `Error: Cannot find module '/Users/traviskerr/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
    MacBook-Air-2:~ traviskerr$`

Please help me figure out what went wrong and what I can do to fix it!
I am very new to this and haven't got a clue of what went wrong. 
Much appreciated, thanks!

I have installed Homebrew and Xcode because apparently those are needed for Node.js however this does not seem to be working properly.

The expected result should say: Hello World on the next line but it is giving me

```
`Error Cannot find module '/Users/traviskerr/index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
MacBook-Air-2:~ traviskerr$`
```

instead...

Comment: This file exists and is in this folder ? '/Users/traviskerr/index.js'

Comment: Ok thanks for the response how then do I access it? What should I type in the terminal? @VitorPiovezam

Comment: Where is your `index.js` file? The error is telling you it is not in the directory where you are running your `node` command. If you type `ls` do you see the file listed there?

Comment: It's from a folder in visual studio code @MarkMeyer is there a way to access that in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely because you're `index.js` file doesn't exist within the current directory that you're running the command `node index.js`

Regardless of windows/mac, the following steps should get your file to run (assuming your `index.js` code is correct)

1. Open a new terminal
2. Navigate to the directory where your `index.js` is by running `cd <path_to_index_directory>`
3. Run `node index.js`

If you're in the correct directory, running `lst` should list the file. If you don't see your file in the list, you're not in the correct directory (thus resulting in module not found)

Comment: Hi mwilson when I typed cd <path_to_index_directory> I got the following: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: Don't actually type the literal "<path_to_index_directory>". That is a placeholder for the actual file path to your file. Example: `cd myFolder/myApp`

Answer (score 0):

In vscode explorer, give a **right click in your project name and click on the option "Reveal in Explorer".**

This is your project folder and you must to **run node index.js inside your project folder**, opening a terminal in this folder.